# How to provide test flags when debugging a single test?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, delve

How can I pass test flags (e.g. the `-test.v` and `-test.vet=off` flags) to the test program when debugging a single test, i.e. when I use the `Go: Debug Test at Cursor` functionality?

The `go.testFlags` section from the workspace settings contains these settings, too - but it seems that they only have an effect when *running* the test (`Go: Run Test at Cursor`).

I am using Visual Studio Code 1.61.2, vscode-go v0.28.1, and the dlv-dap that is auto-installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue might come from [`src/goTest.ts#_testAtCursor()`](https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/blob/6df88866aa9ac8c215993e91061507ec41ae115b/src/goTest.ts#L59-L65)

```golang
    if (cmd === 'debug') {
        return debugTestAtCursor(editor, testFunctionName, testFunctions, goConfig);
    } else if (cmd === 'benchmark' || cmd === 'test') {
        return runTestAtCursor(editor, testFunctionName, testFunctions, goConfig, cmd, args);
    } else {
        throw new Error(`Unsupported command: ${cmd}`);
    }
```

There is no `cmd, args` when calling `debugTestAtCursor()`, as opposed to `runTestAtCursor()`.
That could mean this is not supported in the current implementation.